# The typescript shows an error "Object is possibly 'undefined'"

Tags: typescript

I define an object of multiple fees that is annotated by an interface. The interface includes an index signature, a readonly property and an optional property. When I declare the function to calculate the total fee, TypeScript warn me that the object is possibly undefined. Since I know the the optional property can be undefined, I have used a type guard to check if the value of every property is not undefined in the loop. Unfortunately, it does not work. Please help me. Below is my code:

```
    interface FeeObjType2 {
      [index: string]: number | undefined;
      readonly book: number;
      food: number;
      vegetable: number;
      newBook?: number;
    }
    
    const feeObj2: FeeObjType2 = {
      book: 20,
      food: 14,
      vegetable: 13,
    };

    //ADD NEW PROPERTY TO THE CURRENT OBJECT
    feeObj2.newBook = 17;
    
    //FUNCTION TO CALCULATE THE TOTAL FEE
    const sumFunc = function (feeObj: FeeObjType2): number {
      let total = 0;
      for (const property in feeObj) {
        if (property && feeObj[property] !== undefined) {
          total = total + feeObj[property];**//The error takes place here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**
        }
      }
    
      return total;
    };
```

Comment: This is currently a limitation of TS as per [ms/TS#10530](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530); since `property` is of nonliteral type `string`, the compiler is unable to narrow indexed accesses at that key. The recommended workaround is to copy to a new variable first like `const x = feeObj[property]; if (x !== undefined) { total = total + x; }`. Or you could collapse the whole thing to `total += feeObj[property]??0`.  Both methods are shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/Wyo4bN). Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz! I kind of understand that since property is not literal (it can be number or undefined) and compiler is not able to narrow the types even if we use the if condition to attempt narrowing the types. In this case, we need to store the value of each property in a variable. I know how to solve the problem now, but I still do not understand the root of the problem. Or we just say that this is a drawback of the TypeScript Compiler.

Comment: I will explain more when I write up the answer.

Comment: I did my best to explain what's going on; microsoft/TypeScript#10530 is the issue tracking the problem, and you can read more about it there if you want.  Hopefully they will address it someday by supporting narrowing based on identity of keys instead of just the type of keys.

Answer (score 4):

This is currently a limitation of TypeScript as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530).

---

You're expecting that by checking `feeObj[property] !== undefined` that TypeScript will [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type of `feeObj[property]` from `number | undefined` to `undefined`, but unfortunately that isn't happening.  TypeScript does normally allow such [equality narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#equality-narrowing) on property accesses, as shown here:

```
function works(feeObj: FeeObjType2) {
  const property = "someProp";
  feeObj[property] + 2; // error, possibly undefined
  if (feeObj[property] !== undefined) {
    feeObj[property] + 2; // okay
  }
}
```

That works because `property` has the string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of `"someProp"`.  The compiler knows the exact literal value of that key.  And so after you check the `"someProp"` property key of `feeObj` for `undefined`, the compiler will realize that it cannot be `undefined` inside the subsequent code block, and allow you to treat it like a `number`.

So then why doesn't the following work?

```
function doesNotWork(feeObj: FeeObjType2, property: string) {
  // (parameter) property: string
  feeObj[property] + 2; // error, possibly undefined
  if (feeObj[property] !== undefined) {
    feeObj[property] + 2; // still error, possibly undefined!
  }
}
```

It's because the type of `property` is `string`, which is *not* a literal type, and currently the narrowing behavior operates only on the *types* of the property keys, not their *identities*.  From the type system's perspective, the above code is the same as:

```
function alsoBad(feeObj: FeeObjType2, property1: string, property2: string) {
  if (feeObj[property1] !== undefined) {
    feeObj[property2] + 2; // error of course
  }
}
```

Here you're checking `feeObj[property1]` and then accessing `feeObj[property2]`.  It makes sense that this wouldn't be safe, right?  You might be thinking "of course that's not safe, because `property1` and `property2` might not have the same value, while `property` obviously has the same value as *itself*."  But the compiler isn't tracking identities of the keys, so it doesn't know that the comparison is to "itself".

Going through the same exercise with `property1` and `property2` both being of the same literal type `"someProp"`, you'll see that it starts working again:

```
function alsoGood(feeObj: FeeObjType2) {
  const property1 = "someProp";
  // const property1: "someProp"
  const property2 = "someProp";
  // const property2: "someProp"
  if (feeObj[property1] !== undefined) {
    feeObj[property2] + 2; // okay
  }
}
```

So currently, the only way you can narrow an object's type by checking its property is if you check a property of known literal type.

---

The recommended workaround in cases like this is to copy the property to a new variable before checking it.  This way you are always narrowing the same variable:

```
const sumFunc = function (feeObj: FeeObjType2): number {
  let total = 0;
  for (const property in feeObj) {
    if (property) {
      const fp = feeObj[property]; // copy
      if (fp !== undefined) { // check
        total = total + fp; // okay
      }
    }
  }
  return total;
};
```

Of course in the particular example you don't need to be so verbose: there's no real reason to check `property` for truthiness (if someone wrote `feeObj2[""] = 123`, would you *really* want to exclude it from the sum?); you can replace `x = x +` with the [addition assignment operator (`+=`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment); you can use [the nullish coalescing (`??`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to handle `undefined` instead of having a separate code block.  That gives you:

```
const sumFunc = function (feeObj: FeeObjType2): number {
  let total = 0;
  for (const property in feeObj) {
    total += feeObj[property] ?? 0; 
  }
  return total;
};
```

which should behave similarly without needing to rely on narrowing of `feeObj[property]` at all.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQDEpQPICMBWAKgJ4AOUATKgN7CqoDa4AJlAB4BcqAzhDOAHMAulzABXALa5YqAD6oxYVnHBRmAbjqoYUBMwD2YADbFUuffoDWoydJib6cC8xtTYD1ADcoAqBAS4RlCudh5gUADuAEIWlgD8Ie7AAL7AwEiGvKhwWHj4FFyYOAQk5FQAvDRa5lZcFAAMADRaTvouqACMACzN9N6+-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-kIH1aCOghVBRTZDkaW5eto1E8SkJgkUWVkiUtGUijiAqaSNPFeSeSUzIxN0lCZKMrklyww9VPwt0PSInc-VJQNsJlCyqLHaNY3jehEzSGZ0HuZZfgASWwZYzguW5ZgAGQeBLZkIG5CGuWLCESjBVlWdIzJ4SR0HhKT2NTX9+MEohCQoIlEhgdygjEiBs3-KT6g8JxGsxHToIw39PNIjDl104ayUKuBSDK+z1yEXy+RpAL9xGrDpsIr1XP9M8kAACygJBLC0FbUFa-wr0qM72tVKaFv847A1SfcntQF6dAgRjfyuoxNAmNJlO4Yr4X08qfzswsMGlCD6tQcQ3EagNUGa062ou1BOpaNE7T61SBoPQFhu+lVKk83Dh1QOI4nRhaAB4AFo6dO3aQG4DDWagbxf10Y1YDfeh3s+lHzt+9QgA)

Comment: Thank you @jcalz for your detailed explanation. I eventually understand why this happens. Have a good one sir.