# TS Object is possibly undefined with guarded clause

Tags: typescript

I have the following code

```
if(!g) {
  g = {
    group,
    access: acc 
  }
  this.rules.push(g)
}

else if(!g.access) {
  g.access = acc
}

else if(!g.access[resourceType]) {
  g.access[resourceType] = {
    list: [],
    fallback
  }
}
else if(!g.access[resourceType].fallback) {
  g.access[resourceType].fallback = fallback
}
```

For some reason in my last `else if` body I get the error that `g.access[resourceType]` is possibly undefined, but the situation when that property is undefined is clearly handled in the code above. Can I fix this without simply suppressing the error?

Comment: That happens because you need to put g.access into a variable and then check the variable

Comment: Either you can check the whole structure of g and then tell in the guard function that it's of some nested object

Comment: I think that the logic of this script can be simplified a lot if you don't do so much checks and just return something like { access: {resourceType: {fallback: fallback} };

Comment: Please provide a [mre]; right now I get a bunch of errors unrelated to your question because the values are not defined.

Comment: I think you should tell what you are trying to accomplish with so many checks

Comment: I'm inclined to close this as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75903134/the-typescript-shows-an-error-object-is-possibly-undefined/75903598#75903598) but I'll wait for a [mre] to be sure (unless OP can just tell me that it's the same issue)

Comment: @jcalz the provided link solved my problem.