# typescript not detecting I check for existance - "

Tags: typescript, tsc

I have an optional `scale()` function, and even though I check for it's truthyness, typescript (both tsc and the vscode extension) still gives me the `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2722)` error in this code:

```
const scaledValue = registers[desc].scale
  ? registers[desc].scale(rawValue)
  : rawValue;
```

[image]

However, if I assign `registers[desc]` to another variable, type script is smart enough to know I have checked for existance of .scale(), and gives no error in this code:

```
const register = registers[desc];
const scaledValue = register.scale
  ? register.scale(rawValue)
  : rawValue;
```

I also tried `const scaledValue2 = typeof registers[desc].scale === 'function' ? registers[desc].scale(rawValue)`, and it still gives the same typescript error.

This does not seem to happen all the time, so I was wondering if anyone knows when it does happen, and is there any config I can change to make it never happen?

Extra info:

```js
type MeasurementType =
  | "Voltage"
  | "Current"
  | "Power"
  | "Energy"
  | "Frequency"
  | "PowerFactor"
  | "AlarmStatus";

type MeasurementDetail = {
  lsb: number;
  msb?: number;
  scale?: (raw: number) => number;
  units: string;
};

const registers: Record<MeasurementType, MeasurementDetail> = {
  Voltage: { lsb: 0, scale: (raw: number) => raw / 10, units: `V` },
  Current: { lsb: 1, msb: 2, scale: (raw: number) => raw / 1000, units: `A` },
  Power: { lsb: 3, msb: 4, scale: (raw: number) => raw / 10, units: `W` },
  Energy: { lsb: 5, msb: 6, scale: (raw: number) => raw, units: `Wh` },
  Frequency: { lsb: 7, scale: (raw: number) => raw / 10, units: `Hz` },
  PowerFactor: { lsb: 8, scale: (raw: number) => raw / 1000, units: `` },
  AlarmStatus: { lsb: 9, units: ` alarm code (0=no alarm)` },
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "ES6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

*Update*

Even when I switched from a for-in loop to a for loop, and remove `desc`, I still get the error:

I renamed `type MeasurementType` to `type Attribute` for clarity.

```js
type Attribute =
  | "Voltage"
  | "Current"
  | "Power"
  | "Energy"
  | "Frequency"
  | "PowerFactor"
  | "AlarmStatus";

type MeasurementDetail = {
  lsb: number;
  msb?: number;
  scale?: (raw: number) => number;
  units: string;
};

type Measurement = {
  type: Attribute;
  value: number;
  units: string;
  humanReadable: string;
  timestamp: Date;
};
export async function readRegisters(
  client: ModbusRTU,
  attributes?: Array<Attribute>
) {
  try {
    if (attributes === undefined) {
      // define the default attributes (which is all of them for now)
      attributes = [
        "Voltage",
        "Current",
        "Power",
        "Energy",
        "Frequency",
        "PowerFactor",
        "AlarmStatus",
      ];
    }
    console.log({ clientId: client.getID(), isOpen: client.isOpen });
    client.setTimeout(500);
    const values = [];
for (
  let attributeIndex: number = 0;
  attributeIndex < attributes.length;
  attributeIndex++
) {
  const measurement:Attribute = attributes[attributeIndex];
  let rawValue = 0;
  const lsbRegister = measurementDetails[measurement].lsb;
  const msbRegister = measurementDetails[measurement].msb;
  try {
    if (msbRegister) {
      // msb is optional, if present we do it first then multiply by 2^16
      console.debug(
        `reading msb for ${measurement} from register ${msbRegister}`
      );
      const result = await client.readInputRegisters(msbRegister, 1);
      rawValue = result.data[0] * 65536;
      console.log(
        `raw measurement for msb: ${result.data[0]} * 65536 = ${rawValue}`
      );
    } else {
      console.log(`Skipping msb for ${measurement}`);
    }
    console.log(
      `reading lsb for ${measurement} from register ${lsbRegister}`
    );

    const result = await client.readInputRegisters(lsbRegister, 1);
    console.log(`lsb = ${result.data[0]}`);
    rawValue = rawValue + result.data[0];
    console.log({ rawValue });

    const scaledValue = measurementDetails[measurement].scale
      ? measurementDetails[measurement].scale(rawValue)
      : rawValue;

        values.push(`${measurement} is ${scaledValue} ${measurementDetails[measurement].units}`);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      } finally {
        console.log(`Done`);
        console.log(values.join("\n"));
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try `typeof registers[desc].scale === 'function' ? ...`?

Comment: When I put your first example on the TS Playground I cannot reproduce your issue: https://tsplay.dev/w6VOYw

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina yes I tried that, no luck, updated the question with the fact I tried this also.

Comment: @ChrisBarr Yes I see! What tsconfig is the platground using? Let me check...

Comment: @ChrisBarr I can't see any diference in the playground's config and mine. I tried changing a few settings in your playgorund, and I could not reproduce it either. I can't see how to export that playgrounds settings to a tsconfig.json file either - that would be good to do.

Comment: Please provide the declaration for `desc` so that this could be a [mre].  I'm betting the issue is probably that `desc` is wider than a single string literal type and so this is probably ms/TS#10530 and the same as [this q](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75903134/2887218).  But without an actually reproducible example I can't be sure.

Comment: @jcalz desc was defined in the containing loop: `for (const descUntyped in registers) { const desc = descUntyped as MeasurementType;` for-in loop. I have refactored a bit, I will put now working code in as an answer.

Comment: @NULLpointer yes I know, very strange right? I tried to make it's config match yours and I was also surprised it had no import feature. Perhaps you are using an older version of TypeScript?

Comment: Does [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WoMELN) both demonstrate your issue and show how to deal with it?  If so I might post an answer (if nobody closes it as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75903134/2887218) or maybe others.) If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz https://tsplay.dev/WoMELN illustrates my question, not the answer. As I say in my question "However, if I assign registers[desc] to another variable..." - I don't think I should need to assign it to an intermediate variable just for typescript's sake. My question is WHY do I need to assign JUST to stop typescript giving a false error? Your linked possible duplicate does answer it by linking to the bug "Discriminant property type guard not applied with bracket notation" git hub issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530. Post that as an anwer and I will accept it.

Comment: If it illustrates the question could you please [edit] to use that code so it's a [mre] people can copy and paste?  It also helps if the approach you don't like were also shown as code and not just English words so you might do that as well, so you can point to it and say "I don't think I should need to do this".  Or, if you'd rather and if you don't mind, I'll edit your post to do that. Then someone can answer with ms/TS#10530.